# How to check single input text box for multiple values?

Tags: php, html, forms, csv, range

I want to create a site where users can check prize bond numbers, and I know a bit about php as well, so I created a form in html:

```
<form>
    Enter your price bond number <input type="text" name="number"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="try your luck">
</form>
```

Now in php, I want to check if it's a single number, range number, or comma-separated number, e.g.:

```
1023342
1023342-10233100
1023342,1023343,1023344,1023345
```

I want to take different actions based on what user entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function check_input($number){
  if(ctype_digit($number)){
   //case1: simple number
   return 1;
  }
  if(preg_match('/(\d)-(\d)/', $number, $out)){
   //Case2: range
   //we need to check if the range is valid or not
   if($out[1] >= $out[2]){
    //echo 'error: the first number in range should be lessthan second number';
    return false;
   }
   return 2;
  }
  if(preg_match('/\d+(,\d+)+/', $number, $out)){
   //Case3: comma seperated
   return 3;
  }
  return false;
}

//usage
if(check_input($number) == 1){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: good one, one question why are u returning 1 in ctype_digit($number) condition

Comment: and where is this $out variable coming from ?

Comment: The $put variable generated by PHP preg_match if it matches, it's an array according to grouping. ctype_digit check if the $number is contains only numbers then its case 1

Answer (score 1):

```
$mynumber = $_POST["number"];
$pieces = explode(",", $mynumber);
if(count($pieces)>0)
echo "Comma separated";
$pieces = explode("-", $mynumber);
if(count($pieces)>0)
echo "Range Value";
else
echo "Single Value";
```

The above code is usefull in a way, at the end you will have array of number to process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
strpos
```

like this

```
if (strpos($str,',') == true) {
     echo "it has comma";
} else if (strpos($str,'-') == true) {
    echo "it has hyphen";
} else {
     echo "single number";
 }
```

put your respective functionality in if condition by replacing echo.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<?php
 $value=1023342;
 if (preg_match("-", $value)) {
     echo " - was found.";
  } else if(preg_match(",", $value)){
     echo " , was found";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "it is a simple number";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that all of the other answers are a little under-cooked considering what a user *might* submit as input.  I decided to write a comprehensive solution that will remove invalid values and generate an array of valid values for your continued processing.

Code: ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45ee266dac8776f01032b074c19c504296a567b1) & [Regex Pattern Demo/Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/MzNb97/1))

```
// declare limit that value ranges cannot exceed (for project-specific reasons
//   and/or to avoid memory limitation failures)
$limit=100;

$result=[];  // declare an empty array
// split on commas, and filter out any invalid values
foreach(preg_grep("/^( ?(\d+-\d++|\d+),?)+$/",explode(',',$input)) as $chunk){
    if(strpos($chunk,'-')===false){
        $result[]=(int)$chunk;  // cast value as an integer for uniformity
    }else{
        $range=explode('-',$chunk);
        if(($size=abs($range[0]-$range[1]))<=$limit){
            $result=array_merge($result,range($range[0],$range[1]));
        }else{
            echo "Value range ($range[0] to $range[1]) size ($size)
                  exceeds allowed limit ($limit)";
        }
    }
}
```

After running this code block, you can use the values in the `$result` array as needed for your project.

My code will allow users to:

- add a space before and/or after commas
- entry single values
- enter multiple comma-separated values
- enter ranged values
- enter a mix of single and ranged values as comma-separated values

My code will filter out:

- non-numeric values
- range values with more than 1 dash in the range expression
- range values that don't begin and end with a number
- empty values