# Is it possible to take more than one input from a textbox in a php form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a calculator program in php code.

I made it using html and javascript, but I've been told to use php code for the logical part.

Is there any way we can take more than one input from a textbox, in a php form ?

Comment: yes, but do you mean take a list of values from a single textbox, and turn it into an array, or do you mean take an array of values from several textboxes and turn them into a list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how check single input text box for multiple values in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052436/how-check-single-input-text-box-for-multiple-values-in-php)

Comment: and could you put some example code in your question?

Comment: yes. It is possible. Get data from textform and separate it as your desired output.

Comment: @TangoAlpha Link to How does accepting an answer work?: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352329

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily use multiple inputs in a form, by giving them different names and accessing them through `$_REQUEST['input_name']`.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, what I am doing is taking the selected checkboxes from the popup and putting them into the text input field in the main form as a comma-separated list.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="entry-r1" placeholder="place" tabindex="1">
    <a class="show-lookup button" href="#" id="popup-r1" tabindex="2"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    <div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="lookup-multiselect" id="lookup-r1">
        <a class="button close-button right">x</a>
        <form action="" id="form-r1" name="form-r1" method="post">
            <input class="checkall" id="checkall" type="checkbox">
        <label for="checkall" class="narrow">Select all</label>
            <p class="category" id="checkboxes-r1"><strong>Select...</strong><br>
                <input class="js-popup-focus" type="checkbox" name="place" id="antwerp" value="Antwerp" tabindex="3"> <label for="antwerp">Antwerp</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="place" id="berlin" value="Berlin" tabindex="3"> <label for="berlin">Berlin</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="place" id="cairo" value="Cairo" tabindex="3"> <label for="cairo">Cairo</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="place" id="duss" value="D&uuml;sseldorf" tabindex="3"> <label for="duss">D&uuml;sseldorf</label><br>
            </p>
        </form>
            <a href="#" class="button close-button right" tabindex="4">Use selected</a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background: #333;
}

.lookup-popup, .lookup-multiselect {
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: none;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5em;
    left: 25%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () 
{   

    /* get id of form to work with */

    $('.show-lookup').click(function()
    {
        var pairedId = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
        var lookupToDisplay = '#lookup-' + pairedId[1];
        $('.overlay').show();
        $(lookupToDisplay).show();
        $('.js-popup-focus').focus();
    });

/* put value selected in lookup into field in main form */

    $('.lookup-popup input').on('change', function() 
    {  
        var fieldname = $(this).attr('name');
        var pairedId = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('-');
        var selOption = $('input[name='+fieldname+']:checked').val(); 
        $("#entry-"+pairedId[1]).val(selOption);
    });

/* for checkbox version, append selected values to field in main form */    

    $('.lookup-multiselect input').on('change', function() 
    {  
        var pairedId = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('-');
        //event.preventDefault();
        var selOptions = $(".category input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
          return $(this).val();
        }).get(); // <----
        //console.log(selOptions);
        var selectedString = selOptions.toString();
        $("#entry-"+pairedId[1]).val(selOptions);
    });

    $('.close-button').click(function()
    {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        var pairedId = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('-');
        $('.overlay').hide();
        $("#entry-"+pairedId[1]).focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: as I said in my comment on the question, I am not quite clear about what is being asked for, so the above may turn out not to be useful here - but it creates a user-friendly way of putting a comma-separated list into a single textbox, which can then be parsed as an array by the PHP page that the form is submitted to